# Ajax call and images path showing 404 in published asp.net mv web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an mvc application in .net 4.8 framework
Everything is working fine on local development environment but when I host it on server , every ajax call , images shows 404. Below is my findings.

Under IIS we have a named website and under that website we have a application, our code is deployed inside application and the below is how the url looks like when it show 404

https://example.com/Controller/ActionMethod

After adding ApplicationName it works

https://example.com/ApplicationName/Controller/ActionMethod

Below is my ajax call

```
var url = '/Controller/ActionMethod
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {},
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {}
    });
```

Why ApplicationName is not part of any url (ajax , image) here, can someone suggest what changes I have to make here ? Below is the current and expected url

Current

https://example.com/Controller/ActionMethod

Expected

https://example.com/ApplicationName/Controller/ActionMethod